# Aeson Example not working

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm following the Aeson [library documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) but their example doesn't seem to work for me:

Code:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson
import Control.Applicative ((<$>),(<*>))
import Control.Monad

instance FromJSON Person where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Person <$>
                         v .: "name" <*>
                         v .: "age"
  -- A non-Object value is of the wrong type, so fail.
  parseJSON _          = mzero

data Person = Person
              { name :: Text
              , age  :: Int
              } deriving Show
```

Error report:

```
ghci> decode "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}" :: Maybe Person

Couldn't match expected type `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
            with actual type `[Char]'
In the first argument of `decode', namely
  `"{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}"'
In the expression:
    decode "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}" :: Maybe Person
In an equation for `a':
    a = decode "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}" :: Maybe Person
```

Am i doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `decode` expects a `ByteString` and you are passing a `String`.

Try this in `ghci`:

```
:m +Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
decode $ pack "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}" :: Maybe Person
```

In real code you shouldn't use the `Char8` module as it just truncates `Char`s to 8 bits without taking any account of encoding. Generally you should aim to start out with a `ByteString`, e.g. by reading it from disk using the functions in `Data.ByteString.Lazy`.